# 60Hz to 50Hz Conversion

Tags: 240v

I need to convert 220V 60HZ to 220/230V 50hz for use in a consumer Super Automatic Espresso Coffee machine, 1,400 watts.
I assume running it at 50Hz is possible, it's an expensive machine so wish to be safe and run it at 50Hz. There are grinders, gears and boilers in the machine. The manufacture in Italy is no help at all.

The electrical Label on the machine is 230V 50Hz 1,400 watts no mention of 60Hz.

I am not able to build and would like to buy a converter. 
Can anyone recommend a source, I can only find industrial units on the web.

thank you!

JC

Comment: Just leaving as a comment because there are a few more variables than I would be comfortable with. If this is an expensive machine you can purchase a variable frequency drive. I have done this to convert single phase to 3 phase but there are single phase to single phase models the drive takes the 240v 60hz and you set the output to 50hz at your desired voltage. This will cost several hundred $ but then your motors and heating elements would have the proper frequency / voltage and may well be worth it. I use yaskawa brand drives because of a low cost high quality product.

Comment: I checked Alibaba and e-Bay for VFD and it's given me a huge headache Ed!Many are reasonable price USD $100 but they are so complicated and I don't understand the technicals. I don't need motor control, breaking or variable just 60Hz input to 50Hz output no messing around. Can these device be "set and forget" to change just the frequency for a coffee maker? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you want is an online sinewave UPS built for the European market.  That will input *don't care* Hz power and output 50Hz power at all times.

We're not a shop-for-you site, so you'd have to go elsewhere for advice on *which one*.

The important features are

- Online, which is a specific subtype of UPS, indicating output is inverter-driven at all times, using all-the-time *double conversion*, and it never bypasses and serves line power directly.
- Sinewave, to make the motors happy.
- Output of 230V to satisfy your Eurogadget.  The input voltage does not matter, so bonus points if you can find one rated for  120V-240V input, and the ability to input varying voltages strongly suggests it is a double conversion unit.
- Listed by a [Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationally_Recognized_Testing_Laboratory). Most European testing labs are qualified bevause their standards are equivalent to ours.  CE won't qualify, it is not a testing lab, it is only a promise from the manufacturer, is widely falsified, and effectively stands for Chinese Excrement.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar. But key question (since I've never tried this myself - always just 60 Hz for me): Will the UPS actually "get" power from the 60 Hz side (to then turn into 50 via AC-DC-AC)? Or will it look at 60 Hz coming in and say "I don't know what's coming in, but it isn't close enough to 50 Hz so I'm tossing it"? In any case, I suggest adding the key words **double conversion** somewhere in the answer. Without those words, it is easy to get fooled by the various terminologies that all amount to "*nearly as good as* a true online UPS" when in fact that is not the case.

Comment: @manassehkatz makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to help educate the effects of frequency on electrical items.
http://www.50hz60hz.com/frequency-converter.html
If I understand correctly, you are wishing to run a 50Hz device on 60Hz power. 
Provided the voltages are within range then you should be able to do it without problems.